# regex to change time value past midnight

Tags: regex, timestamp, splunk

I've an application log whith timestamps from 01-24 (instead of 00-23), I'm trying to do a search and replace "24" with "00" eg

```
15.03.2012 24:59:58 - SIRENG INFO  com.app.funnction.info
15.03.2012 01:01:02 - SIRENG INFO  com.app.funnction.moreinfo
```

Should return

```
15.03.2012 00:59:58 - SIRENG INFO  com.app.funnction.info
15.03.2012 01:01:02 - SIRENG INFO  com.app.funnction.moreinfo
```

So far i've got

`([0-9+]+).([0-9]+).([0-9\.$]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)`

Comment: I love to share this link for anyone having issues with regex's http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ realtime regex creation just copy text to window and watch it go as you build the regex..

Comment: Also a good rule of thumb to follow make your regex as specific as possible ie. first number goes no farther than 2 right? so use [0-2] not [0-9] not a killer in this situation just good to practice to use this always.

Comment: I've edited your question (you want to change "24" to "00", not "23"). But one question remains: Are you sure that the `24:nn:nn` time doesn't have yesterday's date as compared to `00:nn:nn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for this regex

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]{4}) 24:([0-9]+:[0-9]+)
```

or if [shorthand character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) are supported by your regex engine, you can use this regex

```
(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}) 24:(\d\d:\d\d)
```

and replace it with

```
$1 00:$2
```

- $1 = first group: `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]{4})` will match `15.03.2012`
- $2 = second group: `([0-9]+:[0-9]+)` will match `59:58`